# MVVM, two synchronized Grid Data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, gridcontrol

I want to do a control for adding and removing items from a two list (Selected and UnSelected), like this:

[image: Screenshot of control]

But I can't find a good way to do this; how can I use the GridData (or similar control like GridControl of Devexpress) for binding two List and modify it?

Problems:

- I can't use ObservableCollection with this control
- I can't bind the SelectedItems

If you have any suggestion or sample for some work, it will be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use two observable collections? One for selected and one for unselected. It seems to be the easiest way to implement such functionality.

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> _unselectedItems = new ObservableCollection();

    public IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItems { get { return _selectedItems; } }
    public IEnumerable<Item> UnselectedItems { get { return _unselectedItems; } }

    private void UnselectItems()
    {
        MoveFromOneCollectionToAnother(_unselectedItems, _selectedItems, ...);
    }

    private void SelectItems()
    {
        MoveFromOneCollectionToAnother(_selectedItems, _unselectedItems, ...);
    }

    private void MoveFromOneCollectionToAnother(ICollection<Item> source, ICollection<Item> destination, IEnumerable<Item> itemsToMove)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsToMove)
        {
            source.Remove(item);
            destination.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's true I tried some work like that, but my problem is, I can't bind this list with SelectedItems of my GridControl. I have two Grid and i want select one or more element and when i click the Grids are updated.

Comment: @rad, wait, `GridControl.SelectedItems` doesn't sound like correct property. There should be smth like `ItemsSource` there.

Comment: @Snowbear I populate ''GridControl'' with 'ItemsSource', but I just want to move the selected items, and my problem is that this proprety does not exist... I don't want to move all the source of the grid, just the selection.

Comment: @rad, it seems to be an issue of specific grid control.

Comment: @Snowbear I think it's the same with WPF `DataGrid` Control

Comment: @rad, regular DataGrid has selected items: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: @Snowbear thank you so much for your help, i found a solution with your help :)